# Having trouble installing mongodb on ubuntu version 18.04 LTS

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I've recently installed Ubuntu version 18.04 LTS and just started to learn to use use linux and terminal. I want to install mongodb. I'm following the steps from [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#packages) website.

i ran the following lines in the terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

after i run the fourth line the following appears

```
tasif@Tasif-Dell:/$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
[sudo] password for tasif: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then when i want to start mongodb the following message is displayed

```
tasif@Tasif-Dell:/$ sudo service mongod start
[sudo] password for tasif: 
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

installing libcurl3 fixed it for me

```
sudo apt install libcurl3
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no non-development release of MongoDB for 18.04 yet. (Current as of 2018-07-12)

https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/ shows that there's only a dev release.

Your specific problem is that you are not installing all the dependencies for Mongo, which can probably be fixed with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Per [this ask Ubuntu answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214746/how-to-run-apt-get-install-to-install-all-dependencies)

Comment: it didn't work ......any other solution or should i just install the previous version of ubuntu?